# Nullpointer exception in Jpanel Paint

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am making a 2d game in java on eclipse and am working on level design. I am getting the following runtime exceptions in my run mode:

```
`at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.Pane.paint(Pane.java:30)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.Pane.paint(Pane.java:30)`
```

And so on.
This is my paint method:

```
`public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        for(Block[] b : blocks)
        {
            for(Block bx : b)
            {
                //System.out.println(bx.letter);
                g2d.drawImage(bx.bpic, bx.x*32, bx.y*32, this);
            }
        }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }`
```

Block is initialized into a 2d array. What is wrong?

Comment: You need to add the stack trace.

Comment: You need to add a lot more than the stack trace. You need to finish your question.

Comment: and you using wrong method `paint(Graphics g)` for (`todays Java6`) Swing `JComponents` you have to change that to the  `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `g.dispose();` in the end. You are disposing the Graphics object to be used next time.

Since the object is not created by you, you don't need to dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error occurs due to one of the followings

1. You have forgotten to initialize some component.
2. You are trying to add components on the frame or panel which is not yet initialized.

Try to execute the code by Removing the followings

1. super.paint(g);
2. g.dispose();